# How to call javascript file in html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to call `innerHtml` in JavaScript its working in the same file but not in the separate JavaScript JS file. 
my working code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function my()
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello";
    } 
    </script>
<div id="abc" onmouseover ="my()"> hi hw ru  </div>
```

But if I invoke this method in separate JavaScript file its not working even I am giving the source path of the JavaScript file  like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/framemrq.js">
```

Comment: Don't you think it should be: 
    function my(){
         document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello";
     }

Comment: you have to add function <script type="text/javascript">
  function my()


     document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello";
    } 
   </script>

Comment: check your script, have you forget to put `{` after `function my()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the `function` keyword

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function my(){

        // Your code here
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

please define your my function correctly like this:

```
function my() {
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="hello";
}
```